# run many javascript files after angular view init

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using a html template with many scripts these scripts run after document ready but when I use this template with angular I'm facing a big issue that I should call many init functions after angular view init

these files in angular.json like

```
       "scripts": [
          "src/assets/vendors/base/vendors.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/demo/demo4/base/scripts.bundle.js",
          "src/assets/app/custom/general/dashboard.js",
          "src/assets/app/bundle/app.bundle.js"
        ]
```

is there any way to run all one time after angular view init !?

Comment: you don't need to add them in the scripts section to make them available.  Just import them into your app component (or where ever) like `import * as whatever from 'whereever'` and run their init function as you please like `whatever.init()`. ideally you'd put service wrappers around these though and leverage DI.

Comment: Still the issue is exist the angular import script files after html